# javascript critical error script1006: expected ')' for href inside msgBody in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I get the error when I try the following code -

```
Dim email As String = outPutParameter2.Value.ToString()
        If email <> String.Empty Then
            Dim url As String = "mailto:" + email
            Dim subject As String
            Dim msgBody As String
            Dim ProjLink As String = "Click on the <a href='http://abc.gov/Facts/ProjectDetails.aspx?project_pk=" + strProjectid + "'>Link</a>"
            subject = "?subject=Returned Facts Review For Project Number " + strProjNo
            msgBody = "&body=The Facts review has been returned. To check click " + ProjLink
            url = url + subject + msgBody
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "OpenWin", "<script>openNewWin('" & url & "');</script>")
        End If
```

So I tried to use the escape character like -

```
Dim ProjLink As String = "<a href=\'http://abc.gov/Facts/ProjectDetails.aspx?project_pk=" + strProjectid + "\'>Link</a>"
```

Then the whole link shows in the email but I want it to show as the word Link only with the actual path hidden.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

replace `//` with `///`. 
`//` is actually an escape sequence to put `/`. Using `///`  we are escaping the escape character (middle slash). I tried your code with dummy values and it works fine in Windows 10 Mail.
Let me know again.

```
Dim ProjLink As String = "Click on the <a href='http:///abc.gov/Facts/ProjectDetails.aspx?project_pk=" + strProjectid + "'>Link</a>"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. The \' works as escape character and I don't get the error but it shows the whole path in the email. I want to hide the path from the user and show them "Link" or "Click here". If I replace \' with \" as you suggested, it shows error as end of statement.

Comment: @user6771075 Re-check my answer

Comment: @user6771075 mark it as answer if it worked for you or let me know if error persists.

Comment: @V A Thomas - I replaced // with /// after http as you suggested but then it does not open the outlook window at all.

Comment: trace your result link and comment here.